# OnDisconnect and Logged on Users after recycle?

Tags: signalr

I've read that `OnDisconnect` ( *server side*) sometimes , can be bypassed ( application recycle etc).

> The OnDisconnected method doesn't get called in some scenarios, such
>   as when a server goes down or the App Domain gets recycled.

And so I ask :

When a user connects , I generate him a `token`  , keep it in the user `cookie` , and when `OnConnect` is called , I attach a `connectionId` with that token.

*(the same way  where `onDiconnect` is called ,  I set a value in the `dateDisconnected`)*

This will also supports 2 connected users ( **same** browser)

example :

[image]

example :

```
id         tokenId              ConnectionID         DateCreated            dateDisconnected
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1          500                    {1234-1234}          06-07-2013               null             
2          500                    {5432-5432}          06-07-2013               null
```

And here is the problem :

What will happen if a user has logged in (So I write this user in my DB as logged in) , do some chat , and then the server restarted ?

The client will try to reconnect and after 30 seconds it will stop.

**But then** , when the server is UP (after an hour ) - I **STILL** HAVE A LOGGED ON USER IN MY DB. and he is **NOT**. ( well , not with that connection ID anyway...)

How can I solve this kind of problem  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to solve this problem is to log everyone out on application start, aka in your case invalidate/delete all logged in token rows.  Therefore whenever the server comes up the application is in a fresh state with no one logged in.

Comment: Hi:-) I wanted to ask you about that question in Jabbr. ( but i ws offline while you send me message :-) But can you please elaborate about your solution ? I dont think i got it 100% ( someone has also suggested a timer which "keeps alive" db records : e.g. - every minute update a date  in db.

Comment: The basis of your issue is that when the server restarts all your database records aren't entirely cleaned up.  So what I'm proposing is that whenever your application starts (Application_Start) you can "log out" every user in your db.  

So, lets take the scenario when your server restarts and there happens to be 6 left over logged in users in your database.  When your application boots back up and Application_Start is triggered you can remove every logged in user, resulting in 0 logged in users and therefore no zombie entries.